# ArrayList add() sometimes does not add element obtained from Firebase to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

So, I am trying to create a listView that shows the rooms that have an appointment set. The problem is that such rooms and date of appointment are not added into the ArrayLists in some cases. I have to constantly open and close the activity to get a situation where they are indeed added and shown in the ListView.

```
// Global variables
ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
private DatabaseReference appointmentsRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
    // Other stuff
    appointmentsRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    appointmentsRef.child("appointment").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                final Appointment cita = snapshot.getValue(Appointment.class);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("room").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dS) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ss : dS.getChildren()){
                            Room room = ss.getValue(Room.class);
                            if(room.getId().equals(cita.getRoomID())){
                                Log.e("Pass", "Room " + room.getId() + " in appointment " + cita.getId() + " rented room " + cita.getRoomID());
                                rooms.add(room);
                                dates.add(cita.getDate());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.e("Canceled","Cancelled  appointment loop");
                    }
                });
            }
            Log.e("Rooms", rooms.toString());
            Log.e("Dates", dates.toString());
        }



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("Canceled","Cancelled room loop");
        }

}
```

The code always goes through the if conditions where the output is shown as following but the ArrayLists are shown on the logfile as empty.

```
E/Rooms: []
E/Dates: []

E/Pass: Room 1b845370-39d0-4e35-9e15-b9eaf6d556b5 in appointment 1803b7a8-7cfc-4c43-8bad-573868d174f5 rented room 1b845370-39d0-4e35-9e15-b9eaf6d556b5
E/Pass: Room 6640904b-edc6-4b1e-b636-a68cb72241ad in appointment a206e8f5-76e3-40cc-91de-e64a976691e9 rented room 6640904b-edc6-4b1e-b636-a68cb72241ad
```

Update: I moved the Log.e that printed the ArrayLists after the if statement as answered. In fact, the ArrayLists were never empty, so why is it that such Rooms and dates are not shown in the List view from the activity?

```
// Inside onCreate before appointmentsRef
ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.listViewHistory);
// after appointmentsRef
HistoryAdapter adapter = new HistoryAdapter(this, R.layout.history_adapter_view,rooms,dates);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

HistoryAdapter:

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Room> {
private static final String TAG = "HistoryAdapter";
private Context mContext;
private int mResource;
//ViewHolder object
ViewHolder holder;
ArrayList<String> appointments;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView location;
    TextView price;
    TextView date;
    ImageView image;
}

public HistoryAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Room> objects,ArrayList<String> dates) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mResource = resource;
    this.appointments = dates;
}

@NonNull
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //sets up the image loader library
    setupImageLoader();

    //get the Appointment information
    // String currentUser = ""+ FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    //String day = "placeholder";
    String day = appointments.get(position);
    String title = getItem(position).getTitle();
    String location = getItem(position).getLocation();
    String price = "$"+getItem(position).getPrice();
    String imgUrl = getItem(position).getPhoto();

    Log.e("Position","Posición : "+ position);
    //create the view result for showing the animation
    final View result;




    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        holder= new HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder();
        holder.title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        holder.location = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
        holder.price = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        holder.date = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        holder.image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        result = convertView;

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result = convertView;
    }


    // Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
    //        (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.load_down_anim : R.anim.load_up_anim);
    //result.startAnimation(animation);

    holder.title.setText(title);
    holder.location.setText(location);
    holder.price.setText(price);
    holder.date.setText(day);

    //create the imageloader object
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    ;
    int defaultImage = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/logo_size",null,mContext.getPackageName());

    //create display options
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(defaultImage)
            .showImageOnFail(defaultImage)
            .showImageOnLoading(defaultImage).build();

    //download and display image from url
    imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrl, holder.image, options);

    return convertView;
}

/**
 * Required for setting up the Universal Image loader Library
 */
private void setupImageLoader(){
    // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            mContext)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
}
}
```

Comment: You are adding elements by checking the if condition 'if(room.getId().equals(cita.getRoomID()))', you should debug your code and check if after passing the condition you element is added or not.
I am sure that the reason is you if condition.

Comment: All right, so you guys were right about the Log.e showing emtpy arrayList due to being updated asynchronously. I moved them after the if and now it shows that there are indeed rooms and dates added into the ArrayList, then why is it that sometimes the values in those ArrayLists do not show in the ListView from the Activity? Please let me now if I should add additional blocks of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your `if` statement is running inside the `onDataChanged` method, which is asynchronous, and will be run in a different thread.

In other words, you will first `addValueEventListener`, and the code will then immediately move onto the next line of code, where you log the lists.

If you move the logs to just after the `if` statement inside your inner `onDataChanged()`, you will see it is working as expected.

Comment: It was indeed this, thanks everyone. As for why the ListView was empty it is because adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); need to be called after adding values to the ArrayLists.

Comment: I was busy writing an answer that explains this! glad you solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding ValueEventListener on child "room" and then calling `Log.e("Rooms", rooms.toString());` and `Log.e("Dates", dates.toString());` , But the below function will be called in future when the data is changed. That's why rooms and dates are empty.

```
               @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dS) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ss : dS.getChildren()){
                            Room room = ss.getValue(Room.class);
                            if(room.getId().equals(cita.getRoomID())){
                                Log.e("Pass", "Room " + room.getId() + " in appointment " + cita.getId() + " rented room " + cita.getRoomID());
                                rooms.add(room);
                                dates.add(cita.getDate());
                            }
                        }

                       Log.e("Rooms", rooms.toString());
                       Log.e("Dates", dates.toString());
                    }
```

Modify the function like below and then see the output:

```
               @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dS) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ss : dS.getChildren()){
                            Room room = ss.getValue(Room.class);
                            if(room.getId().equals(cita.getRoomID())){
                                Log.e("Pass", "Room " + room.getId() + " in appointment " + cita.getId() + " rented room " + cita.getRoomID());
                                rooms.add(room);
                                dates.add(cita.getDate());
                            }
                        }

                       Log.e("Rooms", rooms.toString());
                       Log.e("Dates", dates.toString());
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayLists are updated asynchronously. Even though the code logging their contents is below the code that updates them, it is actually run first, while they are still empty. If you need to work with them after they are updated, place your code in the callback like this:

```
for(DataSnapshot ss : dS.getChildren()){
    Room room = ss.getValue(Room.class);
    if (room.getId().equals(cita.getRoomID())) {
      Log.e("Pass", "Room " + room.getId() + " in appointment " + cita.getId() + " 
      rented room " + cita.getRoomID());

      rooms.add(room);
      dates.add(cita.getDate());
    }
    // at this point rooms and dates have been populated. place code that needs
    // to work with these populated ArrayLists here.
}
```